# How can I initialize an array with an enhanced for-loop?

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I was optimizing an application and wanted to change my for loops to enhanced loops:

From:

```
for (int m = 1;m < MAX_BEREN;m++)
{           
    Wasberen[m] = new Wasbeer();       
    Wasberen[m].YYY = r.nextInt(SchermY - 28);
}
```

to:

```
for (Wasbeer a : Wasberen)
{
    if (a!=null)
    {
       a = new Wasbeer();
       a.YYY = r.nextInt(SchermY - 28);
    }
}
```

I get a NullPointerException, because it probably doesnt know how much 'beren' can be in
the array, but I'm not sure how to manage the same as the loop above (MAX_BEREN = 11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array reference ('`Wasberen`' in this case) in an enhanced for statement is null, then a `NullPointerException` will result when the statement is executed.

Comment: So I initialize with the 'for' and iterate in later stages with the enhanced loop? Because the 'wasberen' already exist after init

Comment: The NullPointerException could be thrown, given your snippet, from the Wasbeer no-arg constructor or if 'r' is a null reference as well. The stack trace for the exception should identify the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

For initializing arrays, you should stick to the syntax you had before.

Comment: a[i] = new Object(); is not equal to Object b = a[i]; b = new Object();

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the enhanced for-loop in Java to fill an array. (I'm assuming your `Wasberen` array was already created before - if not, this will get you a NullPointerException in both variants.)

Your code (simplified)

```
for (Wasbeer a : Wasberen)
{
    a = ...;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < Wasberen.length; i++)
{
    Wasbeer a = Wasberen[i];
    a = ...;
}
```

This assignment will change the local variable `a`, but will have no effect on the contents of the array.